# Webpack override behavior of require

Tags: json, webpack

I have a module I'm importing during my webpack that does something like so:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  position: true,
  gfm: true,
  commonmark: false,
  footnotes: false,
  pedantic: false,
  blocks: require('./block-elements.json')
};
```

Webpack rewrites this module like so:

```
module.exports = {
  position: true,
  gfm: true,
  commonmark: false,
  footnotes: false,
  pedantic: false,
  blocks: __webpack_require__(/*! ./block-elements.json */     "./block-elements.json")
};
```

Another function is then assuming that the *blocks* member is a string.

Is there a way to override the writing of the **webpack_require** and replace it with my own function that loads the json in a string?

Comment: My current plan is to write a webpack plugin to fix this specific case, but was hoping there was already one that does so.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood. You should be able to use the [raw-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) to load the JSON as a string.

Comment: Thanks that's closer, but the loading function still doesn't work. It expects an object and rawloader gives me a string.

I think I can probably write my own loader that massages the output into an object instead.

Comment: Ah that's not working either. __webpack_require__ adds a 'default' entry for everything. This is also messing up the calling code as it thinks there's a 'default' key.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed by writing my own loader and setting the default property on the module exports explicitly.

```
// Code for the loader
module.exports = function(source) {

  // Just inline the source and fix up defaults so that they don't
  // mess up the logic in the setOptions.js file
  return `module.exports = ${source}\nmodule.exports.default = false`;
}
```

The other script was enumerating the keys of the returned object and the 'default' key was messing it up. However if a key had a type of Boolean it would let it through.

Specifically it was a problem with the remark-parser lib used for hosting markdown in a react control.